# Javalite - render JSON, HTML, XML for all the actions

Tags: javalite

Is it possible to get the same behaviour like in Rails controllers when declared as follows:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    @clients = Client.all
    respond_with(@clients)
  end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the programming pattern is slightly different.

For example, if your URL ends with `.json`, you can do this in controller:

```
public void index(){
      if("json".equals(format())){
          render().noLayout().contentType("application/json");
      }
     view("books", Books.where(...));
}
```

This way, if the request URL is: http://localhost/books, you will get an HTML page served in layout with a menu and a footer, but if it is http://localhost/books.json, then you will have no layout.

For more information, refer to documentation here: http://javalite.io/view-routing

Comment: Thank you very much, Igor !

Comment: Should I always have a view even when returning JSON ?

Comment: I tried as follows: ```public void index(){
        view("lists", List.findAll().orderBy("id"));
        render().contentType("application/json");
    }```, and that didn't work.

Comment: not necessarily, but if your JSON has a more complex structure, you would want to use views to break it down into partials. See this example: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-rest/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/people/index.ftl

Comment: @Belgoros, please take a look at the docs. You need a method `respond()`, not `render()`

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/belgoros/838c83439c07fa9d386ce8027fae4cf3) to show the failing test. Could you tell me what is wrong wit that please ?

Comment: PeopleController used `render`, that's the reason. Is there any example of use of `respond()`, it seems like it just sends the text. How is it possible to pass in the result of `Person.findAll()`, for example ?

Comment: @belgoros, sure just do  this: `respond(People.findAll().toJson()).contentType("application/json")`, (typing from memory).

Comment: I was just 5 seconds late with the same response. Thank you :)